# How to extract GPS from exif using the exif-parser module from Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gps, exif

Necessary  to extract gps coordinates from an image. How can I do it? I can't understand how to use this module

Comment: Could you please provide your code snippets that you have tried or in what point you frustrated. It's too general question to ask in stack overflow.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a tiny script printing out all the info from `exif-parser`:

```
const exif = require('exif-parser')
const fs = require('fs')

const buffer = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/ibiza.jpg')
const parser = exif.create(buffer)
const result = parser.parse()

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
```

Result:

```
{
  "startMarker": {
    "offset": 0
  },
  "tags": {
    "Make": "Apple",
    "Model": "iPhone 4",
    "Orientation": 1,
    "XResolution": 72,
    "YResolution": 72,
    "ResolutionUnit": 2,
    "Software": "4.3.5",
    "ModifyDate": 1315140671,
    "GPSLatitudeRef": "N",
    "GPSLatitude": 38.90983333333333,
    "GPSLongitudeRef": "E",
    "GPSLongitude": 1.4386666666666668,
    "GPSAltitudeRef": 0,
    "GPSAltitude": 0,
    "GPSTimeStamp": [
      11,
      7,
      47
    ],
    "GPSImgDirectionRef": "T",
    "GPSImgDirection": 82.12307692307692,
    "GPSDateStamp": "2011:09:04",
    "ExposureTime": 0.0003315649867374005,
    "FNumber": 2.8,
    "ExposureProgram": 2,
    "ISO": 80,
    "DateTimeOriginal": 1315140671,
    "CreateDate": 1315140671,
    "ShutterSpeedValue": 11.558659217877095,
    "ApertureValue": 2.970853573907009,
    "MeteringMode": 5,
    "Flash": 0,
    "FocalLength": 3.85,
    "ColorSpace": 1,
    "ExifImageWidth": 1024,
    "ExifImageHeight": 765,
    "SensingMethod": 2,
    "CustomRendered": 4,
    "ExposureMode": 0,
    "WhiteBalance": 0,
    "SceneCaptureType": 0
  },
  "imageSize": {
    "height": 598,
    "width": 800
  },
  "app1Offset": 24
}
```

Image used: [image]

Comment: The gps data is inside that data so this solves your problem.